# Android: StartActivity leads to No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=[my.Package.id]}

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I need to start my Activity. The code comes from a library and can not be changed.
It calls basically this

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setPackage(packageName)
intent.data = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")
this.startActivity(intent)
```

the activity to start is declared in my Manifest and looks like that

```
<activity
   android:name="...CustomTabsActivity"
   android:exported="false"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

However I get the error

```
ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {
  act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=... pkg=[my.Package.id]}
}
```

The whole thing works when I add the DEFAULT flag

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

but that is not what I want. I only need to open the Activity when called in specific situations (and I also don't want the app being an option as a default browser in the settings)!

What am I missing? The Activity Intent-Filter ist explicitly set to VIEW so I assumed it might be opened. The PackageID matches. This is my own app, so I don't think I have to export it, right? And even *exported=true* gives the same error.

Comment: android:exported="true" if require to open from outside app

Comment: But the intent comes from a library in my own app. Do I still have to export it then? Aside from that, it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> It calls basically this

That code will not work, because `www.google.de` is not a valid `Uri`. If you want it to match your `<intent-filter>`, you will need to contact the developers of the library and tell them that they need to use a valid `Uri` with an `http` or `https` scheme, such as `https://www.google.de`.

Comment: Sorry, I made simplification of the sample. The URI is actually set with http / https but the whole thing only works when the DEFAULT flag is set. The moment I remove it from the manifest, it fails to find the Activity.

Comment: @TobiasReich: If the library does not add its own category to the `Intent`, `startActivity()` automatically adds `DEFAULT` as a category. And, you need a category match. "The whole thing works when I add the DEFAULT flag... but that is not what I want" -- then contact the library authors and ask them for specific advice.

Comment: Yea, I should but the library is sadly not maintained very actively. But thanks for the suggestion.
But can you explain, why the DEFAULT flag is needed in order to work? I understood it should work without even (just not being the default intent resolver then). But the issue is not that another activity is opened but instead none is found.

Comment: @TobiasReich: "I should but the library is sadly not maintained very actively" -- if it is open source, fork it! "But the issue is not that another activity is opened but instead none is found" -- `setPackage()` on the `Intent` limits the scope of the `Intent` to that package. So, unless *your app* has a matching `<intent-filter>`, including the `DEFAULT` category, there will be no match.

Comment: But I want to limit the intent to my app only. Hence the packageID I gave. But still, why is my own Activity not found? Isn't the intent filter matching then?

Comment: @TobiasReich: "But still, why is my own Activity not found?" -- I tried to explain this [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76505614/android-startactivity-leads-to-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-act-android/76505800?noredirect=1#comment134896203_76505800). If you want to skip the `DEFAULT` category on your `<intent-filter>`, then you need to modify the library to supply a category on the `Intent`. "Isn't the intent filter matching then?" -- no, because the `Intent` requires the `DEFAULT` category, since it has no other category and was used with `startActivity()`.